# WebBrowser control won't display an https site that IE8 on the same PC will

Tags: winforms, internet-explorer-8, webbrowser-control

In IE8, I get the follow warning, but if I choose to continue the site displays properly.

```
  There is a problem with this website's security certificate. 


 The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address.

Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to the server.  
  We recommend that you close this webpage and do not continue to this website.  
  Click here to close this webpage.  
  Continue to this website (not recommended).  
     More information
```

In the WebBrowser control, I get this at first:

```
  Navigation to the webpage was canceled 

   What you can try: 
     Refresh the page.
```

When I hit the refresh teh page, this time, I get the same wanting as I originally get in IE8, but when I click "Continue to this website (not recommended)", the page refresh again, displaying the same warning.

What can I do to get the site to display in the WebBrowser control as it does in IE8. I would've thought that the control would be using the same core logic and therefore expected the same result.

Specifically, the site that I am trying to access is a company Outlook Web Access site. Another issue that I have wit the web browser control when accessing this  site is that, when I click on an email, normally in IE the email opens in a new window. Using the web browser control, I am prompted for a password. Entering one makes the pop up go away but no email is displayed.

Are there any settings on the control that can make the web site behave like it does in IE8 or any other browsder?

Answer (score 0):

Try [display the certificate dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770042(VS.85).aspx) so your user can choose to install the certificate to a trusted certificate store.

To detect if the current web site is showing a secure web site, [handle the DWebBrowserEvents2::SetSecureLockIcon event](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ExtendedWebBrowser.aspx).